# shadowbox content links to a new shadowbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, shadowbox

I am trying to have a shadowbox open, the content of the shadowbox contain one link. When clicked I would like to close down the current shadowbox (box one) and launch a new shadowbox (box two) with the new content inside. Unclear how to achieve this.

Right now my first shadowbox opens wonderfully but so far I cant get the link inside shadowbox one to launch shadowbox two.

Any help is thanked in advance.

my shadowbox code sample

```
<a id="boxone" title="test box one" href="#idofdiv"
rel="shadowbox[linkone];width=300;height=200;">launch shadowbox one</a>
<div id="boxone" style="display:none;">
<a class="boxtwo" title="test box two" href="boxtwo.php"
rel="shadowbox[linktwo];width=300;height=200;">launch shadowbox two</a>
</div>
```

I am using shadowbox 3.0.3 with all "types"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
language: 'en',
players: ['img', 'html', 'iframe', 'qt', 'wmp', 'swf', 'flv']
});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like the jquery plugin "ColorBox" does what I am looking for by default. Im going to swap over and give it a try.

Comment: Colorbox is the answer to my own question. It does what I want by default. Credit goes to Adit Saxena @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050250/shadowbox-how-to-switch-or-replace-content-how-to-close-and-open-another-dial who gave me the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colorbox is the answer to my own question. It does what I want by default. Credit goes to Adit Saxena @ stackoverflow.com/questions/8050250/… who gave me the answer